# How to get two (pseudo)random but distinct from each other container iterators/elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, containers, element

I have a piece of code which generates mini-missions for players to do.
It's simple and to get two different points (start and destination) I have an algorithm which looks like this:

```
    std::vector<std::string> missions;

    missions.push_back("Location_One");
    missions.push_back("Location_Two");
    missions.push_back("Location_Three");

    //make sure our data has at least 2 elements (so we can actually pick two)
    if(missions.size() > 1)
    {
        //Rand(inclusive min, exlusive max)
        int mission_start_location = Rand(0,missions.size());
        int mission_end_location = Rand(0,missions.size());

        if(mission_start_location == mission_end_location)
        {
            //avoid possile infinite loop of calling "Rand" by Add/Decrement-if-equal algorithm
            //basicly if mission_start_location == 0
            if(!mission_start_location)
                ++mission_end_location;//or = 1, we have at least two elements so index 1 is valid
            else
                --mission_end_location;//so we won't got out of range
        }
        //do mission
    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }
```

This works, however I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve what I want, "the C++ way".

My questions are:

- Is this the best way to get two different values from a container?
- What about non-integer-index containers (e.g. `std::map<std::string,std::string>`)?
- - How would I get two different and random values from it?

Note: I'm highly aware of the `do { } while(rand1 == rand2)` method. I want to avoid this because it *can* go into a infinite loop (knowing my luck it will in the production code).

Comment: Your two random values are not _independent_: `mission_end_location == (mission_start_location-1)` is more likely than other choices. That's probably not what you had intended?

Comment: this is the only way I can come up with to avoid the same "Random" number without possibly calling Rand() and infinite amount of times (eg somehow rand will return 0 always, then what?) - doesn't happen but I want to avoid this in the future

Comment: @jogojapan that's what I would like to avoid too if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have that another way.

```
  if(missions.size() > 1)
  {
    size_t const m_size = missions.size();
    // get random number in the full range
    int const m_start = Rand(0, m_size);
    // get another number in a range reduced by 1
    int m_end = Rand(0, m_size-1);
    // if we are equal or above start we shift by 1 up
    if (m_end >= m_start) ++m_end;
  }
```

```
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |
```

If your first selection picks 4, virtually remove it by having the second random number on range-1.

```
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4(was 5) |  5(was 6)  |  6(was 7)  |
```

To map the second random number back to the original indexation just add 1 if you're above the first random number since those indices were shifted by 1 due to "removal" of the first index.

---

This way, each index that is not selected in the first `Rand()` call is chosen with the same probability by the second call to `Rand()`. (If your `Rand()` implementation provides such proper distribution of random numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

```
int mission_start_location = Rand(0,missions.size());
int mission_end_location;
do {
  mission_end_location = Rand(0,missions.size());
} while (mission_end_location == mission_start_location);
```

I don't think there is a more C++ way of doing this. You could randomly shuffle the missions container using the standard library function [shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), but that would have the side effect of randomly shuffling the container, and it's overkill for just getting two random elements.

If you really want to do this with exactly two calls to your random number generator:

```
int mission_start_location = Rand(0, missions.size());
int mission_end_location = Rand(0, missions.size() - 1);
if (mission_end_location >= mission_start_location) ++mission_end_location;
```

I don't know what `Rand` function you're using, but you might want to look at the functions implemented in [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: this is exactly what I want to prevent (again this comment) - the possibly but higly unlikely infinite-loop

Comment: @Gizmo: Ok, I provide an alternative. But as everyone has said, worrying about an "infinite" loop in this scenario is a waste of time. The alternative solution I provide is fine for two elements, but it is hard to generalize, while the loop is easy.

Answer (score 0):

> •Is this the best way to get two different values from a container?

This would generate different values, but you could possibly get an index that is out of range because you increment and decrement. I would suggest just re-generating one of the mission locations while it equals the other instead of incrementing, as that will also remove some bias that incrementing causes. Also, I don't know why you have the `if(!mission_start_location)` block, what are you trying to achieve with this?

**EDIT** I saw that you were worried about infinite loops. You shouldn't be. This is the most standard C++ way to generate non-equal random numbers, and your chances of entering an infinite loop are **extremely** unlikely, even if your vector has size 2 (in which case, it will take on average 2 iterations to guarantee that you have picked a new number).

---

> •What about non-integer-index containers (e.g. std::map)?
>
> •How would I get two different and random values from it?

Most of these should have a `begin()` iterator. You could use this to get something random by <strike>adding a random value between 0 and `size()`</strike> incrementing it in a `for` loop a random number of times (my original solution would not work because `std::map begin()` does not allow the `+` operator, but does allow the `++` operator) (see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) for reference for map. You shold be able to find other containers here too).

Comment: if(!mission_start_location) is basicly if(mission_start_location == 0), which means the other is zero too, and we know we have more than 1 elements, so we add one to mission_end_location which effectively becomes 1. (not out of bounds) Regenerating a random value can possible fall into the "infinite loop"-range and that is what I want to avoid!

Comment: `std::map` does not provide a random-access iterator.

Comment: Okay, but why would `mission_start_location == 0 -> mission_end_location == 0`? This is not always true. In your example, your vector has size 3. Thus, `mission_start_location` could be `0`, and `mission_end_location` could be `2`. Then, with your code, you would increment `mission_end_location` and get an index that's out of bounds

Comment: if(mission_start_location == mission_end_location) :) I never increment if mission_start_location is higher than 0, in that case you can see the code decrements

Comment: Note this is assuming your `Rand(0,missions.size())` function will generate values from `0` *inlusive* to `missions.size()` *exclusive*. If it in includes `missions.size()` then you run the risk of an out-of-bounds index, and if it excludes `0`, then you obviously won't ever get `0`

Comment: @Gizmo read my edit, as I know you are concerned about infinite loops. You really shouldn't be. Although it is theoretically possible, `rand()` (which I'm assuming you're using within `Rand()` is set up in such a way that you really don't have to worry

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you're doing now is one way of using C++, but not necessarily the best one. Let's first examine the code below where most of the logic are:

```
    ...
    int mission_start_location = Rand(0,missions.size());
    int mission_end_location = Rand(0,missions.size());
    if(mission_start_location == mission_end_location)
    {
        if(!mission_start_location)
            ++mission_end_location;
        else
            --mission_end_location;
    }
    ...
```

<strike>I'll assume that your `Rand()` function uses the first argument as the lower *inclusive* bound and the second argument as the upper *inclusive* bound of the possible generated number.</strike>

Doing `Rand(0,missions.size());` would put you into a risk of **reading past the end** of your vector. Remember that `std::vector`'s indices are 0-based, and when `Rand(0,missions.size());` happens to return a value equal to `missions.size()`, then you'll be reading the element one past the end of the vector. You should do

```
Rand(0,missions.size() - 1);
//                     ^^^ THIS
```

instead.

Another one is on this part of your code

```
    if(mission_start_location == mission_end_location)
    {
        if(!mission_start_location)
            ++mission_end_location;
        else
            --mission_end_location;
    }
```

Doing `++mission_end_location;` and `--mission_end_location;` poses you, again, the risk of reading not just past the end of your vector, but also before its start element.

One correct way of doing what you're trying to do is

```
if(missions.size() > 1)
{
    int mission_start_location;
    int mission_end_location;

    while(true) {
        mission_start_location = Rand(0,missions.size());
        mission_end_location = Rand(0,missions.size());

        if(mission_start_location == mission_end_location) continue;
        else break;
    }

    //do mission
}
```

This code loops until `mission_start_location` and `mission_end_location` are different.

Comment: this is a possible infinite loop (altough highely unlikely, but still possible and I want to avoid that), luckily my rand is upper exclusive bound (min+ rand() % (max-min) if (max-min) != 0). I added some comments to the code to clarify my thinking.